# Access violation when trying to get the database context in a hosted service

Tags: asp.net-core, dbcontext, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I'm trying to do a periodic job on my `clients` using a hosted service. This is my hosted service:

```
namespace Commander.Services
{
    public class UpdateClientsStateService : IHostedService, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly ILogger<UpdateClientsStateService> logger;
        private readonly IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory;
        private Timer timer;

        public UpdateClientsStateService(ILogger<UpdateClientsStateService> logger, IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
            this.scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            timer?.Dispose();
        }

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            timer = new Timer(o =>
            {
                using var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope();
                var clientRepository = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<CommanderDbContext>();
                var clients = clientRepository.Clients;

                foreach (var client in clients)
                {
                    logger.LogInformation($"{client.Id}");
                }

            }, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to get the CommanderDbContext service, iisexpress says:

```
The program '[16808] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
```

This is my ConfigureServices

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<CommanderDbContext>(opt => opt.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySql")));
        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
        services.AddScoped<IRequestRepository, SqlServerRequestRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IClientRepository, SqlServerClientRepository>();
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddHostedService<UpdateClientsStateService>();
        services.AddSingleton(o =>
        {
            var accessor = o.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
            var request = accessor.HttpContext.Request;
            var uri = string.Concat(request.Scheme, "://", request.Host.ToUriComponent());
            return new PaginationUriService(uri);
        });
    }
```

Comment: can you try and say this another way, I can't understand it: *As soon as I comment getting the service and just logging a text, everything becomes as expected.*

Comment: @JeremyThompson I mean just logging a text periodically is OK. It's obvious, so I deleted the sentence.